# Selecting dropdown value shows a Textbox, but doesn't stores a value passed in it

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

my view contains

```
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            @{
                List<SelectListItem> deformitylevel = new List<SelectListItem>();
                deformitylevel.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "hip", Text = "Hip" });
                deformitylevel.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "knee", Text = "Knee" });
                deformitylevel.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "ankle", Text = "Ankle" });
                deformitylevel.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "other", Text = "Other" });
            }
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DeformityLevel, deformitylevel, "--Select Level -", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "showdeformitytextbox()", id = "deformitydropdown" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeformityLevel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeformityLevel, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "deformitytextbox" ,style= "display:none"} })
        </div>
```

My function is

```
function showdeformitytextbox() {
        if ($("#deformitydropdown option:selected").text() == 'Other') {
            $("#deformitytextbox").show();

        }
        else {
            $("#deformitytextbox").hide();
        }
    }
```

When I select "Other" in dropdownlist it stores 'other' in the database instead of storing a value which is entered in @Html.EditorFor.

What I'm forgetting Help!!

Comment: You need to do something to prevent the dropDown from submitting its value for DeformityLevel.  Since you are using the same model properties for both the drop down and text box, and you aren't doing anything to hide the drop down, it's going to submit the value in the drop down as an intended value for model.DeformityLevel

Comment: @stephen.vakil I have tried hiding the drop down, same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by others, to make this cleaner, it would be best if you separated the model fields for the drop down and the textbox.  Even if you get it to work using the below code, it will lead to more work if you have to return to the page with the other value selected.  That said, the following does properly submit the expected value in the textbox.  The key concept is to set the dropdown to disabled as you submit.

Assuming your form has an id of `submitForm` specified as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("someActionName", "someControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @id="submitForm"}))
```

Then the following code will ensure that the drop down doesn't submit its value by intercepting the form submission:

```
   $("#submitForm").submit(function () {
      if ($("#deformitydropdown option:selected").text() === "Other") {
         $("#deformitydropdown").attr("disabled", true);
      } else {
         $("#deformitydropdown").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
   });
```

Comment: Ya, this is a better option than my suggestion... grab the right value on submit.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the names of your current controls and make a hidden form element for DeformityLevel.  Then set its value in javascript based on DropdownList and textbox change events.

***Something like this (jq not verified, just for illustration)

```
<select id="DeformityLevel_DDL">
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="DeformityLevel_TB" />
    <input type="hidden" id="DeformityLevel" name="DeformityLevel" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#DeformityLevel_DDL').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() != 'other') {
                    $('#DeformityLevel').val(this.val());
                }
            });

            $('#DeformityLevel_TB').on('change', function () {
                $('#DeformityLevel').val($(this).val());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: this is the way to go if you're not willing to change your model or controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your function only display the `#deformitytextbox` input, when the value entered there changes you should also update the model property.
If the form submits automatically on select change you should use [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Answer (score 0):

Try now with TextBox, your parameter for htmlAttributes is incorrect. Try:

```
<div class="col-md-3 ">

        @Html.DropDownList("DeformityLevel", deformitylevel, "--Select Level -", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "showdeformitytextbox()", id = "deformitydropdown" })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("DeformityLevel", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.TextBox("DeformityLevel", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "deformitytextbox", style = "display:none;" })
    </div> 

    <script>
        function showdeformitytextbox() {
            if ($("#deformitydropdown option:selected").text() == 'Other') {
                $("#deformitytextbox").show();

            }
            else {
                $("#deformitytextbox").hide();
            }
        }
    </script>
```